# Could a creature with dolphin-level intelligence created and raised in a lab be able to understand enough human language to follow a tv show?

Tags: intelligence

I have this idea in my head of a giant creature that was made in a lab, handlers and staff found they can calm it down by turning on a tv show it likes. One day however the relationship of 2 characters in the show ends and causes the creature to get upset, but to do this the creature would need to understand english to some extant so my question is, would this creature in a lab with dolphin level intelligence (the creature is a bipedal combination of ungulates animals) be able to understand english at least enough to follow a tv show?

Comment: Would even a human held in similar conditions be able to understand the language? Whom would they have to speak to?

Comment: This might be of interest to you : [An experiment about teaching dolphins to understand and talk to humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Howe_Lovatt). It's not "just" understanding a tongue, though, and as far as I know, the experiment conditions could be... Strange at times. The results weren't to NASA expectations.

Comment: Also, side note : a lot of understanding is about understanding facial emotions and motions. That's why you don't necessarily need text in silent films to get when people are getting angry at others, or are reconciliating. Make the experience at home, take a movie, cut the sound and see how far you can understand the story and character relationships :).

Comment: Following a TV show actually requires quite considerable level of both language knowledge and cultural knowledge.

Comment: OR you have the individual reacting purely to what it can perceive. One individual hitting another, or using an aggressive tone, or wearing a color that is upsetting (the mean guard wears orange...). Otherwise, you're asking about the intelligence of a fictional engineered animal who can do anything you want it to.

Comment: This is definitely impossible if we only give the dolphin language ability. Appreciating the significance of a romantic breakup requires far more than simply understanding words. Imagine being a fluent English speaker who meets a specialist like an engineer, lawyer, or chemist, capable of spouting a bunch of true techno-babble. You'd be completely unable to follow the conversation, but not because you don't recognize the words they use. Or try this one (_without_ the internet): "my dad is a friend of Bill W." Very basic vocabulary, but completely opaque to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 4):

### The lab creature isn't really understanding what it's all about

So your lab creature is obviously stressed sometimes, it needs to be calmed down, to be able to comply to the experiments your protagonists want to perform on it, of course. Now supposed your animal has intelligence of a dolphin. You keep it in a lab, so your lab is illegal, but let's suppose this is all happening.

Anyway, let's ignore the ethic considerations..

Your creature with the intelligence level of a dolphin does not actually *grasp* the conversation, it doesn't know what it is about. It likes to listen to babbling people in TV shows. Normally, your TV show involves happy people, telling happy stories about their success in life.. now suddenly, you have two folks quarreling. Raising their voices, maybe screaming at each other.

That sounds quite different.

Your creature is not language-aware, or it is only rudimentary language-aware, like dolphins. But.. it is *very* aware of the intonation of human speech, which represents the *emotional content* of human conversation. Like a pet (e.g. a dog) would be sensitive to intonation. When two people quarrel, it sounds.. frightening..

Edit: when the TV person looks into the camera lens, the creature could interpret the result as a direct confrontation.

Comment: This kind of behavior can be more focused if one of the character quarreling represents something to the creature, like they look closely to someone it has formed a bond to. This can let some arguing happening as long as the character in question isn't part of it.

Comment: @Tortliena ok the camera perspective could play a role, the angry person looking into the camera .. btw from personal experience I know dogs don't need to be actual participant in a quarrel, to feel uncomfortable. They are social animals, used to observe other individuals in their pack. Maybe intelligence will suffice: sympathy or identification with a person on TV may be in reach for this creature. Research indicates dolphin and other intelligent animals have the ability to play with internet https://read.nxtbook.com/ieee/spectrum/spectrum_na_september_2019/elephants_dolphins_and_chimps.html

Comment: ... thx, added a remark.. when the creature would feel it is a participant - TV person looking into the camera - that would raise more stress.